# How to use before in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber

How can I use "before" to create the driver instance and launch Firefox in cucumber feature file.

I am familiar with background but never used before.

Comment: This is a very broad question that I'd guess is not answerable in the current form, aside from providing links to documentation on Cucumber's @Before.  Do you have any attempts at code that you could post?  What language are you trying to use, even?

Answer (score 1):

This example is taken from [ToolsQA](http://toolsqa.com)

Let’s do some easy and small example of Cucumber Hooks just to understand the concept.

```
    Feature: Test Hooks

Scenario: This scenario is to test hooks functionality
    Given this is the first step
    When this is the second step
    Then this is the third step
```

***Step Definitions***

```
package stepDefinition;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class Hooks_Steps {

    @Given("^this is the first step$")
    public void This_Is_The_First_Step(){
        System.out.println("This is the first step");
    }

    @When("^this is the second step$")
    public void This_Is_The_Second_Step(){
        System.out.println("This is the second step");
    }

    @Then("^this is the third step$")
    public void This_Is_The_Third_Step(){
        System.out.println("This is the third step");
    }

}
```

****Note***: There is no logic used in the step definitions. Just printing the step summary log.*

Now hooks come in the picture, in case of your scenario, you will like to initialize the driver here.

***Hooks***

```
package utilities;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class Hooks {

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(){
        System.out.println("This will run before the Scenario");
    }   

    @After
    public void afterScenario(){
        System.out.println("This will run after the Scenario");
    }
}
```

Make sure that the package import statement should be import cucumber.api.java.After; & import cucumber.api.java.Before;
Often people mistaken and import Junit Annotations, so be careful with this.

***Output***
[image]

Aparts from hooks, you can make use of other usefull annotations in Cucumber, please refer the tutorial on ToolsQA.com [***here***](http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/cucumber-hooks/).